# Determine what is activated by QAction.activate(QAction.Trigger)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qgis

I'm trying to build a plugin for Qgis where I want to use some functions of a default plugin. I would like to control the options that the user are supose to fill in while using the Interpolation plugin.

So far I have only managed to start the plugin in my python code with:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction
for item in qgis.utils.plugins['processing'].iface.rasterMenu().actions():
    if "polation" in item.text():
        item.menu().actions()[0].activate(QAction.Trigger)
```

Now I want to fill in this form with python code: [image: Image of Interpolation plugin]

But I can't figure out what I activated with "item.menu().actions()[0].activate(QAction.Trigger)", I've searched through the children of "item.menu().actions()[0]" but I can't find any with the title "Interpolation plugin" or anything else on the picture :(

Comment: Try to use `dumpObjectInfo ()` for the given **QAction** to check the connected SLOT(S). I don't know about the Python bindings. For the native CPP implementation you have to compile your (and possibly the whole Qgis) in DEBUG mode.

Comment: I dosen't return anything :( I can trigger the plugin with `QAction_object = qgis.utils.plugins['processing'].iface.rasterMenu().actions()[5].menu().actions()[0]; QAction_object.activate(QAction.Trigger)` or I also mange to run the call for the plugin with: `QToolButton_object = qgis.utils.plugins['processing'].iface.rasterMenu().actions()[5].menu().actions()[0].associatedWidgets()[0].children()[-2]; QToolButton_object.click()` however in both cases `QAction_object.dumpObjectInfo()` and `QToolButton_object.dumpObjectTree()` doesn't return anything.